# Нужно нажать на кнопку Play с помощью JS, как это сделать?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, swf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно нажать на кнопку Play с помощью JS, как это сделать?

Ссылка на сайт - http://www.floridacollections.net/

Мне нужно, чтобы видео воспроизводилось сразу после загрузки, а не с такой длительной задержкой.

```
<script src="http://www.floridacollections.net/iSpeakVideo.js"
type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var video=new iSpeakVideo();
            video.src='https://www.myoffshorecorporation.com/noamcohen1.swf?autoplay=1';
            video.height=440;
            video.width=400;
            video.positionFrom='fromTop';
            video.Location.X=-80;
            video.Location.Y=200;
            video.ReferenceID='imgReference';
            video.Intialize();
            function hideWhenFinished() {
                video.HideWhenFinished();
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: Добавить атрибут autoplay="autoplay" к тегу <video>

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy там тег object и embed